# How to custom output of powershell function

Tags: powershell

I am writing a small function to get the file sizes in several pathes. And I have a problem about the function output. Here is my script:

```
function Get-FileSize {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, 
                   ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Path
    )
    PROCESS {
        foreach ($p in $Path) {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $p |
            ForEach-Object {
                $size = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSItem -Recurse | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum + 0
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name = $_.Name
                    Size = $size
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function will output several pscustomobjects. The size property is very hard to read, so I format the `size` property like this:

```
Size = "{0:N2} GB" -f $size
```

While this version is very easy to read, I can not be sort through the `size` property because the type of this property is `string`.

My problem is how can I custom the display style of pscustomobject's property?
For example, the command `Get-Volume` has a nice output.

Comment: An easy and straight forward solution could be to add an easy to read property to the output instead of changing the existing one. So you could add "SizeGB" and still sort for the property "Size".  ;-)

Comment: @Olaf,Yeah, I also though of this solution, but I am curious about how the command `Get-Volume` implements.

Comment: So may read up [about Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: another related topic could be [about typeData.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_types.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: @Olaf, thank you so much. I think I find the answer.

Comment: Cool. I'd like to see the result when you got it.  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading related topic [about Format.ps1xml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-7.1) mentioned by @Olaf, I have solved the problem.
First, I create a customized `Format.ps1xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <ViewDefinitions>
        <View>
            <Name>FileSizeView</Name>
            <ViewSelectedBy>
                <TypeName>MyType.FileSizeInfo</TypeName>
            </ViewSelectedBy>
            <GroupBy>
                <PropertyName>Path</PropertyName>
            </GroupBy>
            <TableControl>
                <TableHeaders>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Name</Label>
                        <Width>50</Width>
                        <Alignment>left</Alignment>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                    <TableColumnHeader>
                        <Label>Size</Label>
                        <Width>15</Width>
                        <Alignment>right</Alignment>
                    </TableColumnHeader>
                </TableHeaders>
                <TableRowEntries>
                    <TableRowEntry>
                        <TableColumnItems>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <PropertyName>Name</PropertyName>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                            <TableColumnItem>
                                <ScriptBlock>
                                    if ($_.Size -lt 1KB) {
                                        $_.Size
                                    } elseif (($_.Size -ge 1KB) -and ($_.Size -lt 1MB)) {
                                        "{0:N2} KB" -f ($_.Size / 1KB)
                                    } elseif (($_.Size -ge 1MB) -and ($_.Size -lt 1GB)) {
                                        "{0:N2} MB" -f ($_.Size / 1MB)
                                    } else {
                                        "{0:N2} GB" -f ($_.Size / 1GB)
                                    }
                                </ScriptBlock>
                            </TableColumnItem>
                        </TableColumnItems>
                    </TableRowEntry>
                </TableRowEntries>
            </TableControl>
        </View>
    </ViewDefinitions>
</Configuration>
```

Second, add the new format file to the current session `Update-FormatData \path\to\file\MyView.Format.ps1xml`.

Third, before I return the pscustomobject in my function, I add the `TypeName` to it. The `TypeName` is defined in node `<ViewSelectedBy>`. Here is the function:

```
function Get-FileSize {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, 
                   ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string[]]$Path
    )
    PROCESS {
        foreach ($p in $Path) {
            Get-ChildItem -Path $p |
            ForEach-Object {
                $size = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $PSItem -Recurse -File | Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum + 0
                $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Name = $_.Name
                    Size = $size
                    Path = $p
                }
                $object | Add-Member -TypeName 'MyType.FileSizeInfo'
                return $object
            }
        }
    }
}
```